# "Could not resolve archetype" error on Maven at Eclipse Oxygen while creating project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am getting the following error while creating a `maven-archtype` project in my Eclipse Oxygen.

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:1.0 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-webapp:pom:1.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org
```

I can access the Maven Repository perfectly well from my browser using following link:

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/
```

I am using my office laptop and its sitting behind a secure network.

By referring answers on other similar questions I have already tried to put `settings.xml` at `.m2` directory. I don't know which proxy to use so I just put my system credentials for `username` and `password` tags. But this did not work.

I have also tried to add Maven_Archtype in Eclipse Maven settings. Still not working.

Has anyone faced this issue? Please point me to a correct solution its its already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

This normally happens when you have already installed Eclipse older version like Kepler or Mars, and then you install newer version separately, this newer version accesses some directories of older version.So,

1. Go to----> `C:\Users\Irfan (your user name)`
2. Delete these two folders `.eclipse` and `.m2` .
3. Reinstall the newer version of Eclipse again.